# Convert reduceEach to swift

Tags: swift, core-location, reactive-cocoa

i'm trying to convert objective c project to swift

heres my code

```
    func didUpdateLocations()->RACSignal {
        return self.rac_signalForSelector(Selector("locationManager:didUpdateLocations:"), fromProtocol: CLLocationManagerDelegate.self).reduceEach({ (manager:CLLocationManager, locations:NSArray) -> AnyObject! in
        return locations
    })
}
```

the error is  Cannot convert value of type '(CLLocationManager, NSArray) -> AnyObject!' to expected argument type '(() -> AnyObject!)!'

with objective c you can pass parameters to block

any ideas

Comment: What is the type of the element you are trying to invoke `reduceEach` on?

Comment: The original code ( https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/3fb9944591f0590a4c344d56bcb6db805871ac85/ReactiveCocoa/Objective-C/RACStream.h#L163-L171 ) relies on Objective-C's weak typing to allow you to pass whatever arguments you want to the block, but the declaration of the block type has no parameters. It looks like you'll have to hack around this somehow.